# Replace string in specific line at specific position of fixed-length file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a fixed-length data file where records are tagged (first 6 characters have a certain string that identifies the record) and I need to replace text from a specific line and a specific position on that line.

```
HEADER   123456
SHIPTO   CODE    123 LANE     HOUSTON    TX
ITEM     ACME BRICK
```

For example, I would like to replace the ship-to code in the above data.  The data can be found in positions 10-17 of the ship-to record (line starts with "SHIPTO").  I'd like to use sed or awk (or other commands) but update the data with a single command line.  If there is more than one SHIPTO line, I am ok with updating them all.

Comment: (1) I’m not sure what you mean by a “fixed-length file”. (2) Positions 10-17 of the ship-to record are `CODE    `. Is that really what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
$ sed -E '/^SHIPTO/ s/(.{9}).{8}/\1NuValue /' file
HEADER   123456
SHIPTO   NuValue 123 LANE     HOUSTON    TX
ITEM     ACME BRICK
```

How it works:

- `/^SHIPTO/`

  This selects lines that start with `SHIPTO`.  The *substitute* command which follows will only be applied to these lines.
- `s/(.{9}).{8}/\1NuValue /`

  This matches the first 9+8 characters of the line and saves the first 9 characters of the line in group 1.  These characters are replaced by group 1, `\1`, and your new value (which, to keep the format, should be 8 characters.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Given the input file:

```
HEADER   123456
SHIPTO   CODE    123 LANE     HOUSTON    TX
ITEM     ACME BRICK
```

And the desire to change the field after 'CODE' where the first field is 'SHIPTO':

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } $1 != "SHIPTO" { print } $1 == "SHIPTO" { $3="0000"; print }' input
HEADER   123456
SHIPTO  CODE    0000    LANE    HOUSTON TX
ITEM     ACME BRICK
```

If your fields are fixed-length and space-delimited and not tab delimited you can use formatted print strings (e. g. `printf( "%20s\t" "$1" )`).